# Editing Image in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing

I wanted to start working on an android application in which i can edit specific parts of the face like nose eyes and lips. This is how it is going to happen. I will take the picture from my camera the application should crop it like eliminating the surroundings environment. Just getting the face to myself and then editing the features of the face. I have done some work on image processing in matlab. Am new to android. I dnt know where to start. Please guide me through to appropriate links. Thank You!

Comment: No response, no query.. isn't my answer helped you?

Comment: ur answer took me to a different dimesion sir. I just researched alot about it. what i want is extract the face off the image i take from my camera. thats the basic operation i want to accomplish. I guess cropping wouldnt help in this case. maybe something related to segmentation for accurate results!

Comment: am greatful to you sir for ur response. I respect that. ur cooperation is appreciated

Comment: Okay.. got your problem. I missed that.. But editing in facial image, i don't know more about that. I have done stickers editing in my project.. if you want, you can check my app just for example. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.solusoft.i2cam.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some tutorial based on "Image Processing", following will help you to start.

- http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

And **[Image Processing Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html)** developed by **JH Labs** will help you to apply effects on your image. You acn download JAR library from [here](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/Filters.zip)

Now, if you want to crop your image, either you can [crop image using camera](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/) or you can write your own code to crop.